# Browser rendering right margin iPhone/iPad/webkit

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad, webkit

I have a html snippet below which renders perfectly in all browsers.  However in webkit on an iphone and ipad, when I pinch the page (so that its smaller), I see a black border which is the background color of the body shining through only on the right edge.   This only happens when I specifiy the width of the .headerpic div.   Since this is the only place in the document I specify the width, I was wondering why it stops short of rendering all the way to the right edge (since this is theoretically the widest part of the document?).

I've attached a photo of what it looks like from my ipad.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

   <head>

    <style>
      body {background-color:#000;color:#231f20;margin:0;}
      #wrapper {background-color:#fff;min-height:1000px;}
      #header .headerpic {height:102px;padding-top:80px;margin:0 auto;width:986px;}
      #footer {color:#fff;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">
        <div class="headerpic">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Photo Of problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will illustrate your problem a little bit clear: http://jsbin.com/ilenu5/5

What I did:

1. I Increased the width of the
   `#headerpic` to 1286px
2. I added a
   background color of `#headerpic`,
   which is red

So the your actual problem is: overflow occured

Why?
because you don't set your `viewport` (`width=device-width`) and the minimum physical width (in px or cm or em) of `body`, so your `body` width by default is 980px, and inherited by `#wrapper`-- so your 986px `#headerpic` overflows the `#wrapper`, and makes your black background appear. Since the overflowed area width is small (986-980=6px), you see a black line.

Comment: Thank you!  I set the min-width of the body to 986px and the problem is fixed in iphone/ipad and doesn't affect normal browsers.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I guess this is a good explanation of why the problem is happening but for me it doesn't really seem to translate to a solution. [This other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15029243/199712) is what fixed it for me.

Answer (score 8):

In my case using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Instead of:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Did the trick!

Comment: This worked for me. Seems like this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Making `#wrapper` `position:absolute` fixes the problem.

Comment: true, this fixes the problem on the iphone/ipad but breaks the design in a normal browser.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And :

```
html, body {min-width:980px; overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Applying

`overflow-x:hidden;`

to one of my divs did it

Giving credit to @starkadh for the inspiration.